# Jquery Dialog box being posted outside the form but I need to submit form on dialog buttons click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is getting tricky, I am unable to post to my form within a Dailog box click. The dialog box once its open its posted outside the form hence the button clicks within the dialog box will not submit the form to the server.  I try to append the dialog box back to the form but the form will automatically post. I neeed to only post to the form when the user clicks either button on the dialog box.  Thanks for your help in advance

**Main View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="main">
        @Html.Partial("_RunLogEntryPartialView", Model)
    </div>
}
```

**Partial View**

```
<button name="submit" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="test();return false;"
    style="width: 100px">
    Upload</button>


 function test() {
        var UploadDialog;

        UploadDialog = $("#uploadConfirmation").dialog({
            title: "Yes or No",
            resizable: false,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#hiddenInput").val("Normal");
                    $("#form").submit();
                },
                "No": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#hiddenInput").val("Buffer");
                }
            }
        });

        //        UploadDialog.closest("div.ui-dialog").appendTo("#form");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than thinking about posting your data from the dialog and the original form, simply use the form values there to fill the values on your original form, close the dialog, then post the original form from the Yes button action via a post.

If you had a lot of values to deal with, you could simply serialize the fields in the dialog, then use an each to post them back to your original form.  If you don't want the user to see the values that you have in your dialog in the original form, then include them as hidden fields or simply use the serialized values from both the dialog and the form in the post.

Alternatively, you could also set a separate form on the dialog from the original form, then submit both serialized values to process the form.  This may actually be the least involved method.

One thing you might want to think about a bit is that using a dialog to interrupt the experience of filling out a form is not considered a great user pattern.  Consider a dialog a critical interruption of a process, that ideally is only used when you must stop the user for a particular reason such as a warning.  Simply having them add more info via a dialog could be accomplished in an easier manner with an expandable area, using show/hide for example.

Comment: Users select files  and then click upload. The upload button once clicked, shows a prompt which lets a user decide which type of parsing to be done to the file, that's why I have the dialog box with two buttons setting specific values. I guess I could use radio buttons or an expandable area if the dialog post does not work.  The problem is that with the Yes button or No, the form does not submit at all. You mentioned "post the original form from the Yes button action via a post" did you mean post using Ajax? If so, Ajax is not an option for my form.

Comment: No, you don't have to ajax values if you don't want.  Both the dialog and your form are in the dom.  So it's simply a matter of taking the values in the dialog's area of the dom and putting them into the form's area of the dom (between the two form tags)  Then submit.